# Please stop moving the interesting tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design

On different pages on SO, the Interesting Tags appear in different places relative to the advertisement and the Related tags:

[SO screenshots http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6369/sointerestingtags.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6369/sointerestingtags.png)

- Exhibit A: http://stackoverflow.com
- Exhibit B: https://stackoverflow.com/questions
- Exhibit C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23
- Exhibit D: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

In the interest of consistency, could they be rearranged so they have the same relative position on each page?

Comment: We need to start a collection and get you some proper tools for drawing arrows! :)

Comment: @MrX: Are my circles OK then?

Comment: Freehand circles are always OK on meta. In fact, they're encouraged on every post.

Comment: I really do NOT want to comment on those, please don't make me!

Comment: Freehand circles are the **only** acceptable circles on Meta.

Comment: +1 Dear lord, i cannot tell you how many times this has pissed me off.