# Favorite Tags location inconsistent, Can we move the section up the side panel some?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

Can we move the favorite list up in the right banner some.

On the main page, it's under the question count and bulletin.
On the recent questions link (the "Questions" button), it moves under the CareerSO ads.
If a filter is applied it's also moved further under the related tags list.

At this point, even with a profile oriented monitor, I'm pushing it being past the first page.

I would expect a design for a sidebar that puts common content at the top, and specialized content below. So at least moving above the related tags on the filtered questions page would make more sense.

Comment: Or the [Interesting Tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60626/please-stop-moving-the-interesting-tags), as they used to be known.